# why the system says :NameError: name 'self' is not defined

Tags: python

My code is similar like this:

```
class NN(object):


    def __init__(self,config=None,opts=None):
        self.file_vars   = ['self.corpusfile','self.dbfile']
        self.corpusfile="data.json"
        self.dbfile="db.json"

    def saveNet(self):
        for name in self.file_vars:
            print(name)
            print(eval(name))
        b=dict( [(name,eval(name)) for name in self.file_vars])



a=NN()
a.saveNet()
```

the result is :

```
self.corpusfile
data.json
self.dbfile
db.json
```

error message is:

> NameError: name 'self' is not defined

how to solve this problem?

Comment: Don't use `eval`. Use `getattr`

Answer (score 3):

The list comprehension has its own local variable scope. `eval` can't see `self`, because `self` comes from an outer scope, and nothing triggers the closure variable mechanism that would be necessary for `eval` to see the variable. (The `self` reference in `self.file_vars` doesn't trigger it, because that expression is evaluated outside the list comprehension's scope, despite being part of the list comprehension.)

Stop using `eval`. It's dangerous, almost always a bad idea, and completely unnecessary for something like this. Appropriate replacement tools might include `getattr`, `self.__dict__`, or something else, depending on what your full use case looks like.